# Get start and end values of kendo slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the start value and end value of kendo slider.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/slider/events.html

I'm using normal slider and not the range slider.For example, lets assume that initial slider value is set to 10 then user slides it to 30 and then i need to get the difference between those two values, which should be 20.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Slider()
          .Name("VariableSlider")
          .Min(0)
           .Max(100)
          .SmallStep(1)
          .LargeStep(10)
                //.Value(50)
          .Events(events => events
              .Change("VariableSliderChange"))

          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "temperature", @style = "width:500px" }))
        <script>
            function VariableSliderChange(e) {

                // get the difference between start and end values here.
            }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the slider doesn't have an API for getting the initial value you should store it immediately after the widget is initialised.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Slider().Name("myslider"))
<script>
var initialValue;
$(function() {
   initialValue = $("#myslider").data("kendoSlider").value();
});
</script>
```

Then you can use it to get the difference in the change event.